# Mopup on Maui - after popup call OnAppearing

Tags: c#, popup, maui, collectionview

I have a collectionview, and when you click on the collectionview item it opens up my mopup popup displaying that data. That works fine. When I click my delete button on the popup to delete that collectionview item my handler deletes and dismisses the popup but I need to figure out how to call OnAppearing on the initial class with the collectionview so that the source for the collectionview gets updated.

I know there is the BackgroundClicked event handler but that is not able to call OnAppearing in another class.

I am currently not using MVVM and not very good at it. Hoping there is an easy way to achieve this.

Edit:

```
private async void DeleteItem_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    
    var result = await DisplayAlert("Delete", $"Delete {Item.Name} from the database", "Yes", "No");
    if (result)
    {
        await App.Database.DeleteItem(item);
        await MopupService.Instance.PopAsync();
    }
    
}
```

Item is the object passed in to the popup that I want to delete via popup menu then update my collectionview on the base class where the popup was launched from initially.

Comment: The `OnAppearing()` method only be called immediately prior to the Page becoming visible. So I recommend you to use the [ObservableCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=net-7.0), It Represents a dynamic data collection that provides notifications when items get added or removed, or when the whole list is refreshed.

Comment: So I currently have it set up as an observable collection - in the popup all I'm doing is removing the object from database that was passed in to popup class. The collectionview still hasn't updated from the source which happens in my onappearing - how can I update the collectionview after deleting the object from another class that only has access to the passed in object and not the observablecollection itself? If that makes sense...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the messagingcenter to subscribe to my popup page from my mainpage, then sent the item back I wanted to delete in my ObservableCollection through messagingcenter.send.

Comment: Sorry about this, I tried to do it then it said I had to wait 24 hours before marking it as the solution...I totally forgot to come back to do that.

Comment: Anyone looking for a good example on this can check out: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/net-maui-good-bye-messagingcenter-welcome-weakreferencemanager/